# External OnTap/OnPressed Passing data (Flutter)

Tags: function, flutter, dart

If

```
onTap: changeName,
 void changeName() {
    setState(() {
         name = "Your own codes";
    });
  }
```

then,
How to pass the data to the changeName function. Like,

```
      onTap: changeName(data),
        changeName(data){
        setState({
        name = data;
        })
        }
```

I have multiple GestureDetector who uses same onTap Function. But, only difference is position that i am passing through the function changeName.

Comment: onTap returns something?

Comment: @Vinz no, just want to use setState there... depends on some data passing through it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem

Comment: @balck-hacker if you want to use setState you can do it easily

Comment: @Vinz Edited, Check now

Comment: In this way changeName expects the onTap to give it `data`, but cannot because onTap does not return `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an anonymous function on your onTap method.

```
void changeName(data) {
  setState(() {
     name = data;
  });
}
```

And onTap:

```
onTap: () {
  changeName(data)
},
```

Hope it helps.